# Load old saved conversation for bot emulator with Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, botframework, bots

I am trying to load the past bot conversation for bot emulator when user triggers in the beginning using Node.js. How can I do it?
I have already saved the conversation in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator does not natively support this.  It is, however, it is an open source project in which you can customize it to do this. I have written an example of how to do this in webchat.  The emulator uses a build of webchat so i'm confident this could be accomplished in the emulator as well.  You can find the example forn web chat I was talking about in [this repo](https://github.com/JasonSowers/ChatHistoryBot-Public)